# Помогите с конструкцией require | ДЗ

Tags: php

Дали дз ,а я не совсем понимаю что от меня хотят(

Сам сам вопрос

*Используя константы и обслуживающие их функции, добейтесь от конструкции require поведения require_once. Иными словами, при многократном включении, код во включаемом файле должен выполниться только ОДИН раз.*

Comment: Вообще, вот это вот *добейтесь от конструкции require поведения require_once* забиваете в поисковик и первая же ссылка дает ответ на вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

```
    function test() {
        if (!defined('TEST')) {
            define('TEST', true);
            require 'test.php';
        } else {
            die('Повторное подключение невозможно!');
        }
    }

    test();
    test(); // Повторное подключение невозможно!
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, определена ли константа. Если нет - определите и выполните код:

```
<?php
// single.php
if (!defined("FILE_REQUIRED")) {
    define("FILE_REQUIRED", "FILE_REQUIRED");
    echo 'hi';
}
```

```php
// index.php
<?php
require 'single.php';
require 'single.php';
```